# Inconsistency and omega-inconsistency (Godel's Incompleteness Theorems)

Tags: first-order-logic, incompleteness

I am reading Godel's Incompleteness Theorems by Raymond Smullyan. On page 57 of the book, it says that is a system S is simply inconsistent, then every sentence is provable in S, and thus S is omega-inconsistent.

I don't really understand why. Please help me.

Comment: Could you expand upon what exactly you don't understand here in a bit more detail so that we can help you?

Comment: Usually written $\omega$-inconsistent and read as  *omega-inconsistent*.  How would you define it?

Comment: Yes, I meant omega inconsistency.

Comment: I am familiar with the principe of explosion. But by consistency, they mean here that no sentence is both provable and refutable (instead of both true and false, in which case the principle of explosion would apply). In other words, why is it that if system S has a sentence that is both provable and refutable, then every sentence in S is provable?

Comment: see [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#Definition) defined at page 56 of Smullyan's book. *Simple consistency* applies to every formal system, while the "omega" version needs a language with arithmetical symbols.

Answer (score 1):

*Simple consistency* and $\omega$-*inconsistency* are defined at page 56.

The definition says:

> if there is a formula $F(x)$ such that the theory proves $\exists x F(x)$ but proves also $\lnot F(0)$, $\lnot F(1)$, and so on, we say that the theory is $\omega$-*inconsistent*.

In a nutshell, it a sort of "limit inconsistency" because the theory asserts that there is something that is $F$ but at the same time proves that all numbers are "not-$F$".

Assume now that the theory is *inconsistent*, i.e. that it proves both $P$ and $\lnot P$. By [Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion): $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$, we have that the theory proves every formulas, and thus it proves the formula $\exists x F(x)$ ans well as all formulas $\lnot F(n)$, being $\omega$-inconsistent.